# Trouble With Splitting In Python

Tags: python, email

I'm trying to make a script in python 2.7 to send an email to a number of people who's data are stored in a text file.

```
import smtplib
email = raw_input("Your Gmail: ")
password = raw_input("Your Gmail Password: ")
txtlist = raw_input(".txt file of receiver emails: ")
content = raw_input("Content of your email: ")
txt = open(txtlist, 'r')
read = txt.read()
read.split(",")
txt.close()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(email, password)
server.sendmail(email, read, content)
server.close()
```

When I run the script I want it to send an email to everybody listed in the text file.
When I run the script an email is only sent to the first person on the list. Please help, thanks!

Comment: have you checked the content of your `read` variable? Is it in `list` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
read.split(",")
```

with

```
read = read.split(",")
```

here is the example (from the docs)

```
 >>> import smtplib
 >>> s=smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
 >>> tolist=    ["one@one.org","two@two.org","three@three.org","four@four.org"]
 >>> msg = '''\
 ... From: Me@my.org
 ... Subject: testin'...
 ...
 ... This is a test '''
 >>> s.sendmail("me@my.org",tolist,msg)
 { "three@three.org" : ( 550 ,"User unknown" ) }
 >>> s.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

As ShpielMeister said, you have to keep track of the splitting's result. 
For example :

```
dummyString = "I like spllitting strings in Python"
dummyStringResults = dummyString.split(" ")
```

will produce ['I', 'like', 'spllitting', 'strings', 'in', 'Python'] which will be stored in dummyStringResults.